# how to add logic in my ng-src angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to add logic as witch image to show

here is some code i think it would work:

view:

```
<img ng-src="{{checkImage(data.image)}}" />
```

js

```
function checkImage(img){
  if(img==1){
    return "image/1.jpg";
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all - your example should work if data.image is an integer and checkImage is a $scope function. What kind of logic do you need?

Comment: i got it to work, the function didnt was a $scope function, my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the function in `ng-controller`

```
function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.image = 1;
    $scope.checkImage = function (img) {
        if (img == 1) {
            return "image/1.jpg";
        }
    }
}
```